combinatorics style number theory
I am unsure of the source of this problem, but i was wondering if anybody had any ideas:
Let $S$ a set of $41$ distinct positive integers, prove that there exists at least one pair of integers in $S$ with lowest common multiple larger than $400$.
I have managed to prove that the largest number in $S$ is no more than $200$, because let $x>200$ be the largest number in $S$ and then since there is at least one number thats not a factor of $x$ (since the 3 digit number with the most factors was 840 i recall) so then the lcm must be atleast $2x>400$. However, not much other progress.
I was wondering anybody could offer any help on this problem.

How do you know that the largest number is no more than 200? Why can't I choose 41 distinct positive integers that are larger than 200?

Try to use pigeon hole theorem.

@CalvinLin because let $x>200$ be the largest number in $S$ and then since there is at least one number thats not a factor of $x$ (since the 3 digit number with the most factors was 840 i recall) so then the lcm must be atleast $2x>400$

Great! I encourage you to add that into the text, to demonstrate that you've been thinking about this problem, and have made some progress. $\quad$
Hint: Show that for $ b > a$, $ LCM(a, b) \geq \frac{ab}{b-a}$. Then show that there are some 2 which satisfy $ \frac{ ab}{b-a } \geq 400$ .  $\quad$ We can generalize to $ 41 = 2 \times n + 1$ and $ 400 = n^2$, where $ n = 20$ in this case.

So you prove that the largest number in the set $S= {1001, 1002, \cdots 1041}$ is no more than $200$?

no? when did i say that all elements in $S$ had to be 1000

@jjagmath OP's phrasing could be improved on. OP showed that if there is an element that is greater than 200, then these exists 2 integers whose LCM is greater than 400.

I would start by thinking about the highest power of $2$ in any of the numbers.  If there is one with $64$ as a factor then no other can have an odd factor greater than $6$.  You can't have $40$ different numbers with none having an odd factor greater than $6$ unless some have a higher power of two in their prime factorization.  Go down the powers of $2$.  As you get lower, think about factors of $3$.

Longwinded answer that explains how to work towards a solution.
In 5.2, we present the actual solution, so skip ahead if desired.
In 5.3, we strengthen the hypothesis to 38 distinct integers. (Reza showed it for 36 distinct integers.)
In 6, we generalize the problem.
Proof by contradiction. Suppose that the LCM is $\leq 400$.
Let the 41 distinct integers be $a_i$ arranged in increasing order.

Note that OP showed that $a_{41} < 200$.

This was obtained by manual verification that any integer from 200 to 400 had fewer than 40 factors. It may not be easily generalizable.


It is well known that $\gcd(a, b) lcm(a, b) = ab$.

This gives us a way to bound $lcm(a, b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a, b) }$, so we need an upper bound for $ \gcd(a, b)$.


A trivial upper bound is that for $ a < b$, $ \gcd (a, b) \leq b - a$

Proof via the Euclidean algorithm, or obviousness.
If we can't push through the solution, we could come back and revisit this bound and see if we could tighten it up more. (Doesn't seem that likely though)


Observe that $ 400   = 20 \times 20 =  \frac{40 \times 40}{4} $. This suggests that:

We need to focus on the larger values.
Looking at $a_1$ to $a_{20}\geq 20$ might not be enough to trigger a contradiction.
If we can't push through the solution, we can revisit this decision of ignoring the smaller values.
We have $ a_{41} \geq 41$.
With $a_{40}\geq 40$, we get $ \gcd(a_{40}, a_{41}) \geq \frac{40 \times 41 } { 400 }$ so $a_{41} - a_{40} \geq   \gcd(a_{40}, a_{41} ) \geq 5$. This in turn increases the bound $a_{41} \geq a_{40} + 5 \geq 45.$.
Likewise, with $a_{39} \geq 39$, since $\gcd(a_{39}, a_{40} ) \geq \frac{ 39\times 40 } { 400}$, so $a_{40} \geq 39 + (a_{40} - a_{39} ) + (a_{41} - a_{40} ) \geq 48$.
We can continue this manually, leading to Reza's solution, starting from $a_{20} \geq 20$.


How can we simplify the argument without tracking individual values?

Let's take a slight detour into making this a continuous problem, namely that if we let $f(i) = a_i$, then $f' \geq  \frac{f^2}{400}$. Show that the solution to $f' = \frac{f^2}{400}$ is $f = - \frac{400}{c + x}$. So if $ f(20) \geq 20$, then $ -20 < c < -40$, and then $ f(40) \rightarrow \infty$. This gives us confidence that $f(40) $ will be "too large"
To discretize this idea, observe that $400 \geq \frac{a_{i+1}a_i}{a_{i+1} - a_i} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a_i} - \frac{1}{a_{i+1}} \geq \frac{1}{400}$. So we have the contradiction (with 40 integers) that
$$\frac{20}{400} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{20} \frac{1}{a_{19+i}} - \frac{1}{a_{19+i+1}} = \frac{1}{a_{20}} - \frac{1}{a_{40}} < \frac{ 1}{a_{20}}  \leq \frac{1}{20}.$$
Note that since OP indicated $a_i < 200$, we could strengthen the hypothesis to 38 integers, and reach the contradiction



$$\frac{18}{400} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{18} \frac{1}{a_{19+i}} - \frac{1}{a_{19+i+1}} = \frac{1}{a_{20}} - \frac{1}{a_{38}}  < \frac{1}{20} - \frac{1}{200}  = \frac{18}{400}.$$

This allows us to generalize the problem to showing that out of $2n$ integers, there must be 2 whose LCM is $\geq n^2$.

Of course, this bound could be tightened further. I'm guessing that we could get it towards $ \geq 3 n^2$  or even $\geq 4n^2-2n$.
Note that $4n^2 - 2n$ is obtained via the first $2n$ integers.




Let's assume $a_1 <a_2< ...< a_{41}$ and there is no such a pair, where $a_i$'s belong to $S$. It's almost obvious that we must have $a_{20} \geq 20.$
Now, note that $a_{21}$ cannot be $21$ since $[20,21]=20 \times 21 >400$. Hence, $a_{21} \geq 22$.
Similarly, we must have:
$$a_{22} \geq 24, \\a_{23} \geq 26, \\a_{24} \geq 28.$$
Since $[a,b]=\frac{ab}{(a,b)} \geq \frac{ab}{a-b}$, we will have:
$$400 \geq \frac{a_{25} \times a_{24}}{a_{25}-a_{24}} \implies a_{25} \geq \frac{400 \times a_{24}}{400- a_{24}} \geq \frac{400 \times 28}{400-28} >30 \implies a_{25} \geq 31.$$
Doing the process several times,
$$ a_{26} \geq \frac{400 \times a_{25}}{400- a_{25}} \geq \frac{400 \times 31}{400-31} >33 \implies a_{26} \geq 34, \\ a_{27} \geq \frac{400 \times a_{26}}{400- a_{26}} \geq \frac{400 \times 34}{400-34} >37 \implies a_{27} \geq 38, \\ a_{28} \geq \frac{400 \times a_{27}}{400- a_{27}} \geq \frac{400 \times 38}{400-38} >41 \implies a_{28} \geq 42 \\\\ a_{29} \geq \frac{400 \times a_{28}}{400- a_{28}} \geq \frac{400 \times 42}{400-42} >46 \implies a_{29} \geq 47.$$
The increase in values seems disappointing, but just in a few other steps,
$$a_{30} \geq \frac{400 \times 47}{400-47} >53 \implies a_{30} \geq 54, \\ a_{31} \geq \frac{400 \times 54}{400-54} >62 \implies a_{31} \geq 63, \\ a_{32} \geq \frac{400 \times 63}{400-63} >74 \implies a_{32} \geq 75,\\ a_{33} \geq \frac{400 \times 75}{400-75} >92 \implies a_{33} \geq 93, \\ a_{34} \geq \frac{400 \times 93}{400-93} >121 \implies a_{34} \geq 122, \\a_{35} \geq \frac{400 \times 122}{400-122} >175 \implies a_{35} \geq 176, \\a_{36} \geq \frac{400 \times 176}{400-176} >314 \implies a_{36} \geq 315, \\a_{37} \geq \frac{400 \times 315}{400-315} >1482 \implies a_{37} \geq 1483.$$
We indeed reached something more than a contradiction!
We are done.

PS:Please notice that there is no need to go through computing so many strict bounds. In fact, we could have proceed as below.
We may assume $a_{25} \geq 30$ as well (please be aware that we already know that $a_{24}\geq 28$ from the solution above).
Since, $\frac{30 \times 31}{2}>400$, we must have $a_{26}\geq 30+3$, and similarly, $a_{27}\geq 33+3$, $a_{28}\geq 36+3$, $a_{29}\geq 39+3$.
Since $\frac{40 \times 41}{4}>400$, we must have $a_{30}\geq 42+5$, and simlarly, $a_{31}\geq 47+5$, $a_{32}\geq 52+5$, $a_{33} \geq 57+5$.
Since $\frac{60 \times 61 }{9}>400$, we must have $a_{34} \geq 62+10$, and similarly, $a_{35} \geq 72+10$, $a_{36} \geq 82+10$, $a_{37} \geq 92+10$.
Since, $\frac{100 \times 101}{25}>400$, we must have $a_{38} \geq 102+26$, and similarly, $a_{39} \geq 128+26$.
Finally, since $\frac{150 \times 151}{50}>400$, we must have $a_{40} \geq 154+51=205,$ which is impossible.
